# How do I filter item(product) with multiple parameter in MongoDB / PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5, mongodb-query

I am using MongoDB with Laravel (php framework).

Using post method I am sending filter parameter to controller function.

**ItemController.php**

```
public function search_item(Request $request){

    $item = $request->all();

    $item =  $this->item->search_item($item);

    return response()->json($item,200);

}
```

**Item.php (model file)**

```
public function search_item($item){

    $items = new item();

    foreach($item as $key => $value) {
        $items = $items::where($key, '=', $value)->get();
    }

    $items = json_decode(json_encode($pro));

    return $items;
}
```

If I pass only one parameter then it's give me result perfectly but if I pass more then one parameter it's give me an error.

> Non-static method Illuminate\Support\Collection::where() should not be called statically

**Let me explain with example :**

**URL** : http://localhost/use_good_store/public/search-item?**brand_name=Bajaj**

If I post above url it's give me perfect result but if I pass more then one parameter like
http://localhost/use_good_store/public/search-item?**brand_name=Bajaj&model=Boxer** it gives me above error.

Comment: No one but you can access URLs at http://localhost. You'd have to put this code up on a server that is accessible from the Internet, or use something like ngrok (which is built into [Laravel Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/valet)  and I heartily recommend. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make it like this :

```
$items = new item();

foreach($item as $key => $value){
   $items = $items->where($key, '=', $value);
}
$items = $items->get();
```

Comment: can you tell me how to write your answer with where , and , or condition ?

Comment: you can use ` $items->where($key, '=', $value)->orWhere($key, '=', $value);`

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things I would change in this code.

First, to address the error you're getting, you're accessing your search method incorrectly. It's an instance method, not a class (or static) method.

So instead of `$this->item::search_items($item)`, it should be `$this->item->search_items($item)`.

But I wouldn't recommend that. Since you're using the model anyway, go ahead and store a static search method on it for future use. It doesn't make much sense for it to be an instance method; you can't really call it on an instance because the point of it is to find many other instances.

Additionally, your query probably isn't going to work out the way you want since you're continually replacing the `$items` value in the for loop. if you're going to be using the QueryBuilder, you can just keep adding `where()` clauses to it all day long.

For this, I'd recommend adding a static `searchItems()` method that returns the results of a query which you would then convert to JSON in your controller, like so:

```
//Item.php model

public static function searchItems($itemSearchAttributes)
{
    return static::where(function($query) use ($itemSearchAttributes){
        foreach ($itemSearchAttributes as $key => $value){
            $query->where($key, '=', $value);
        }
    })->get();
}

//ItemController.php handler method

public function search_item(Request $request){
    $items = Item::searchItems($request->all());
    return $response->json($items);
}
```

Worth noting; your search method here will exclude any records that do not match -all- of the provided key/values.

Comment: your answer is too right but I don't want to change my code structure. your logic is perfect.